# Using Multiple Selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a working jQuery statement as follows

```
 var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable .tableColGroupAssociate");
```

I need to make this more generalized by making .tableColGroupAssociate as a variable. I have achieved this using following:

```
    var hideClass = '.tableColGroupAssociate';
    var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable").find(hideClass);
```

However, it requires a "find". Is there a better performing jQuery way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using String concatenation:

```
var hideClass = '.tableColGroupAssociate';
var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable " + hideClass );
```

jQuery `$(selector, context)` format:

```
var hideClass = '.tableColGroupAssociate';
var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable", hideClass);
```

But internally it implements the `.find()`.

---

## Note

But jQuery always not implements the `find()` method. In modern browsers it try to implement the `document.querySelectorAll()` so that browser will try to parse it as a valid CSS selector.

If this default engine fails then jQuery parse the selector using its default engine ***[Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)*** which using its internal mechanism for DOM traversing.

Comment: Does String concatenation also use find() internally?

Answer (score 3):

you can use multiple strings in selector identifying

```
var hideClass = '.tableColGroupAssociate';
var firstHeaderLineElement = $(".resultGridTable " + hideClass);
```